# Eclipse deletes my .svn folder whenever I restart it

Tags: eclipse, svn, eclipse-plugin, tortoisesvn

I have these installed:

- TortoiseSVN 1.7.0
- Subversion 1.7.0

Eclipse 3.5.2.R35x with these plugins:

- Subsclipse 1.8.0
- Subsclipse Integration for Mylyn 3.0.0
- Subversion Client Adapter 1.8.0
- Subversion JavaHL Native Library Adatper 1.7.0.7
- Subversion Revision Graph 1.1.1
- CollabNet Merge Client 3.0.4

And I'm running windows xp.

I've recently upgrade Subversion to 1.7, and upgraded all the above plugins as well to their latest version.

Now I've discovered this problem:

- I check out a project from my svn server using TortoiseSVN
- I import these projects in my eclipse and use that as my workspace
- Whenever I restart eclipse with that same workspace, and the .svn folder (there's only one .svn folder for the entire project when I upgrade to subversion 1.7) gets deleted.

Any idea what could be causing it? When I was using the previous versions of subversion/tortoise/eclipse plugins, this never happened. I do have Maven integration in Eclipse, not sure if that might be the reason.

Comment: Why not download the project directly from eclipse?

Comment: Are you using Google Plugin for Eclipse?

Comment: I have the same issue.  I think it has to do with using the svn 1.7 working copy format.  Eclipse doesn't like it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

filed as a [bug](http://subclipse.tigris.org/ds/viewMessage.do?dsForumId=1047&dsMessageId=2862505) and fix is in newly released version [1.8.2](http://subclipse.tigris.org/subclipse_1.8.x/changes.html) of subclipse available for [download](http://subclipse.tigris.org/servlets/ProjectProcess?pageID=p4wYuA)